# Grep -A1 -f returns more results than it should

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, fasta

This is my problem:

I have a fasta file with genetic data like so (`my.fasta`):

```
>TR1|c0_g1_i1
GTCGAGCATGGTCTTGGTCATCT
>TR2|c0_g1_i1
AAGCAGTGCAGAAGAACTGGCGAA...
```

I also have a list of names which is a subset of the my.fasta file and I want to pull out the sequences for them (`names.list`):

```
TR3|c0_g1_i1
TR4|c0_g1_i1
```

What I want to get is this:

```
>TR3|c0_g1_i1
CGGATCATGGTCTTGGTCAAAA
>TR4|c0_g1_i1
ATTGGGGGTTTTAAACTGGCGAA...
```

I'm doing: `grep -A1 -f names.list my.fasta | grep -v "^--$" > new.fasta`

But! I have **30566** names in my `names.list` and when I do `grep -c ">" new.fasta` I get **31080**.

I've `grep ">" new.fasta | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '>' > new.names.list`
and then `cat names.list new.names.list > names.all.list`
and `sort names.all.list | uniq -c | grep " 1 " | | sed -r 's/      1 //' > names.extra.list` and ended up with extra 514 names. How did they get there?!

Names list for the whole my.fasta: http://speedy.sh/PQpdD/names.myfasta.list
Names list for the subset I want: http://speedy.sh/kzqKr/names.list

Thanks!

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and add its link to your question.

Comment: Don't you have some names in your `my.fasta` like "TR3|c0_g1_i10"? If you do, several names could be matched by one name from your `names.list`. Can you give some of the extra names?

Comment: Every name is unique since they all represent unique transcripts. I can't upload the files since the results of the research are not published. I checked several extra names and they're not in the names.list file.

Comment: Do you reckon it may not read anything after the "|"? I've uploaded the names lists from all files and added them to the above post.

Comment: @user261007 No, the point is some names could **include** others... Try this: `sed -e 's/^/>/g' names.list > copy.list` and then `grep -A1 -x -f copy.list my.fasta | grep -v "^--$" > new.fasta`.

Comment: I can't post more than too links in the above post, so this is the extras: http://speedy.sh/tuFV3/names.extra.list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your names include each other, for example: `TR74928|c6_g4_i1` and `TR74928|c6_g4_i10`. So `grep` will return you more than one result per line.

To solve this:

`sed -e 's/^/>/g' names.list > copy.list`

to get the names prefixed with `>` just like in your file `my.fasta`, then:

`grep -A1 -x -f copy.list my.fasta | grep -v "^--$" > new.fasta`

to match exactly the lines containing your identifiers.

> -x, --line-regexp
>                 Select  only  those  matches  that  exactly match the whole line.  This
>                 option has the same effect as anchoring the expression with ^ and $.

A simpler solution is:

`grep -A1 -w -f names.list my.fasta | grep -v "^--$" > new.fasta`

but this will work only if no identifier line in `my.fasta` has more than one "word" (the identifier).

> -w, --word-regexp
>                 Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.   The
>                 test  is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of
>                 the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.   Similarly,
>                 it  must  be  either  at  the end of the line or followed by a non-word
>                 constituent  character.   Word-constituent  characters   are   letters,
>                 digits, and the underscore.